# Result of expression 'this.myMethod' [undefined] is not a function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Probably this is a simple question for experienced web devs...
(I started javascript again so)I wrote this class:

```
var FeedParser = function(url){
    this._url = url;
}
FeedParser.prototype.myMethod = function(doc){
    var elem = doc.getElementById('something');
    //do something...
}
FeedParser.prototype.parse = function(){
    var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlRequest.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
    xmlRequest.open("GET", this._url, true);
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("readyState");
            this.myMethod(xmlRequest.responseXML); //ERROR HERE!
        }
    };
    xmlRequest.send(null);
}
```

but when I do

```
var parser = new FeedParser("http://...");
parser.parse();
```

I get

```
Result of expression 'this.myMethod' [undefined] is not a function.
```

What I am doing wrong? I googled it but I couldn't find anything related to my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a scope issue.  `this` inside your `readystatechange` function is not your FeedParser object.  To get a reference to that, try:

```
var self = this;
xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    ...
    self.myMethod(...);
 };
```

Comment: @Chris - NO!!!!!!!!!!  NO NO NO NO NO!!!!!  (Can I say NO a few more times???)  `parser` is an instance of FeedParser.  Do NOT use an instance variable name from within a class function.

Comment: @Chris: This would only work if you only have one instance of the 'class' and you always have to assign an instance to a variable named `parser`... not very convenient.

Comment: @cwolves: why not? @Felix Kling: yes, that is what I'm assuming is the case here.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, I suppose I should have given a reason :)  It's because of the reason Felix gave -- that you can only ever have one instance of the class, it always has to be named the same thing, and you always have to leak a global variable to use it.  It just goes against every single principle of OO design and there's absolutely no reason to do it.  If this was meant to be a singleton instance, it could be written differently: `var parser = {myMethod : funciton(){}, parse: function(){}};`, in which case using `parser` in the object would still be frowned upon, but much less evil :)

Comment: I see, thanks. I've used that in a few projects in which I use the class in question as a singleton. What I don't like about `var self = this;` is that if a lot of asynchronous things are happening at the same, there is the theoretical chance that `self` may be overwritten by another callback function - am I wrong?